# C# FTP connect to specific PATH bypassing the ROOT

Tags: c#, path, ftp, directory

I need  to upload files to a specific folders in my ftp server.
The problem is that the permission to access the ftp is limited to a specific folder which is not the root folder.

> Sending this request gets me the error 550

. 
It looks like my ftp request goes to the root and than changes to the directory. I need to send the request to the specific path. For example, if use mozilla i can easly do it and not receiving error.

> (i receive 550 if i connect to the root path first only)

any ideas?

```
 Uri target = new Uri("ftp://mtftpserver/folder");

    try
    {


        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(target);        
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;

        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;        
        ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        try
        {
            while (bytesSent != 0)
            {
                ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        localFileStream.Close(); 
        ftpStream.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
    }


    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }

    return;
```

Comment: It is the ftp account that dictates where it's own "root" is located. Just giving a hint.

Comment: there is no account.
i can access the folder just by pasting the ftp adress in a normal windows explorer folder. and than i  can copy files in it. 
is possible in explorer, should be possible to automatize it in c#

Comment: All FTP access have an account that goes with it. For the info you are providing, check the guest user for the default root.

Comment: The default user is none, basically empty.
Please notice the part where i said i can access  the folder via any FTP client sw without using credential. Just the folder, if i try with the main root i get 550 anyway.

Comment: With FTP, everything needs an account. For blank accounts, you are automatically logging in as guest user or in case for IIS anonymous which is also mapped to guest user. If you review your FTP server (built in or what), there are 2 sets of default root.. 1 for logged user and 1 for anonymous or guest.

Answer (score 0):

[FTP error codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes)
Error 550 is "File unavailable due to access level"

If you connect to the FTP server without any credentials or account, you are automatically logging in as anonymous or guest user.

A guest user have a predefined root separate from the root folder of logged in users. Normally, the guest, anonymous user have a limited folder to work on.

You are trying to move to the another folder where the default user have no access, this is the one throwing the invalid access error or error 550.